# Certain web content being blocked

Tags: google-chrome, networking, midori, firefox, chromium

For a few months now I've been having this issue where sometimes content from websites are blocked. A few examples are scripts being blocked so I'm unable to log in to certain websites, on Android Studio I have to use an insecure method to download resources (or a system proxy) or it fails, some applications that require a token from online will load up my browser get the token then try to load a local page (127.0.0.1:blah) and give the message "connection refused", etc.

I've tested using different browsers, it is not a problem with a specific one, I've tried Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, Midori, and Opera. It's not an ad blocking extension as I've tried all of those browsers out of the box. It is not a problem with a firewall, I have the firewall disabled in the settings. It is not a proxy problem, I am not using a proxy, it is disabled in settings, however if I use Google's data reduction proxy on chrome it solves the issue with non-local content being blocked. It is not an issue with the router as I have no setting specific to my PC and this issue is not present on my other devices, which means it's a software problem on my elementary OS PC. I've also made sure it's not somehow a hardware issue by installing Ubuntu 15.04 and making sure the issue is not present there.

I am running Freya and I have installed quite a few programs and 3rd party PPA's, I've installed nothing specifically having to do with Firewalls, Proxies, etc. Nor have I added any PPA containing such besides possibly a broad PPA such as getdeb.

I have searched for hours on omgubuntu, linux stackexchange, etc. and have found nothing as this is a very specific issue that I cannot find the solution to.

I've also asked this question already on this stackexchange but it was deleted and I was warned that I am now in danger of being blocked. However it is a good question by the standards posted.

I have done hours of research and have not found a case similar to mine.
It is on topic as it is a question regarding elementary OS that is a problem I only am experiencing on elementary OS. 
It is 3 paragraphs which is pretty specific. 
I tried to make it as relevant to others as possible but it's a very rare issue.

Any input is appreciated and hopefully posting here will help me finally solve this issue that has been plaguing me for months. If you know of a better place for me to ask this question please refer me there.

Comment: have you tried on another OS to ascertain that it's an elementaryOS specific issue?

Comment: will you please provide one of those links--and please respond to @TimothyGray question.

Comment: As I stated in my question I had previously installed Ubuntu 15.04 and verified that the issue was not present.

Answer (score 2):

After trying other search engines and learning their syntax I was able to come across someone who had a similar issue on Ubuntu 12.04 and was able to fix it using

```
sudo dpkg --reconfigure --all
```

Which had me alter a few things like apache and ssl certs. After a reboot I don't seem to be having the issue anymore. I feel bad that I found the answer so soon after I had posted this question but I'm glad my last attempt to fix it was fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

It might have to do something with your hostfile as all browsers have this issue. You can open your hostfile by opening `/etc/hosts`.

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/hosts
```

It should contain something like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   <your pc name>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```